# Creating ArcGIS Online webapp builder Cemetery search?

Tags: arcgis-online, zoom, arcgis-web-appbuilder, relates, search

I created an ArcGIS Online webapp builder app for a cemetery project. I loaded a relationship class into ArcGIS Online that relates plot polygons to a table of interred individuals. It is a 1 to many relationship. I can get the search widget to search the related table and successfully retrieve search results from the related table, HOWEVER, when I click on the results in the dropdown list that correspond to the values in the related table to have it zoom or pan to the related polygon, it tells me no results found.

Has Esri or anyone else figured out a way within the ArcGIS Online environment how to get this to function correctly? (i.e. search related table, get related results, click on result, and pan/zoom to corresponding feature).